# Node.Js: Unable to access values from returned mongodb object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

On querying my mongodb collection, I am getting the following output:

`var test =[{"_id":"54075a2f4cb76dee03052bfa","Pincode":700065,"Country":"India","City":"Kolkata","RoomId":"Bedroom","HomeId":"Mysweethome","MACID":"imp","UUID":"54075954706221ea0389289f","__v":0}]`

However, when I try to access each key-value pair individually using test._id, the output comes out to be undefined! What is the mistake that I'm making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` is an Array of objects. You need to loop through them or access them by index: `test[0]._id`.

Comment: How do I get the length of such an array?

Comment: The "length" property: `test.length`